# iOS Core Plot Get visible labels X axis

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I am using Core Plot and I am really still new to it. I have searched but could not find the answer. I have `allowsUserInteraction` enabled. I have implemented zoom in/out with that. I want to be able to get first and last visible label on X axis every time when user has zoomed in/out. I know that there is `willChangePlotRangeTo` I have called there `expandRangeByFactor` method on my `CPTMutablePlotRange`. I want to be able to get every time text from first and last visible label on X axis. Is there any delegate method that I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to find out what the current axis labels are, call `-layoutIfNeeded` on the axis to make sure the labels are up-to-date and get the set of labels from the `axisLabels` property. Since it's a set, the collection is unordered. You'll have to search the whole set to find the first and last ones. Each label has a `tickLocation` that is the location along the axis and a `contentLayer` that is the label displayed at the location. The automatic axis labels are always `CPTTextLayer` objects, so you can extract the `text` property from there.